# Automount directories only on certain clients via NIS and NFS

Tags: nfs, automount, nis, autofs

Is it possible to serve certain files via NIS only to a group of clients and not to all of them? It's probably a very easy task but I'm searching for a while now and don't seem to find an answer. I'm also pretty new to the subject and not really sure for what to search.

So lets say I have one server (`host1`) that exports a directory via NFS. So the file `/etc/exports` looks for instance like this:

```
/usr/local     192.168.0.1(rw,no_root_squash)
```

Now I want to serve a directory inside `/usr/local` to some client machines. So I edit the file `/etc/auto.master` on the NIS server and add the following line:

```
/usr/local/apps     auto.appXY
```

and I create a file `auto.appXY` with the following content:

```
appXY   -rw,hard,intr    host1:/usr/local/appXY
```

When I have now two clients

```
client1: 192.168.0.1
client2: 192.168.0.2
```

then only client1 will actually receive the content of `/usr/local/appXY` because only its IP address was used in `/etc/exports`. The problem is, that there will be nevertheless an empty directory `apps` mounted in `/usr/local` on client2. Which means means that I can't have a local directory called `apps` because its content will not appear.

So I read this answer:

[How to prevent autofs from mounting over specific directories?](https://serverfault.com/questions/245121/how-to-prevent-autofs-from-mounting-over-specific-directories)

which describes a way of dealing with this by editing the `/etc/auto.master` file on each client. This might work but I was really hoping to find a server side solution.

**So here again my question:**

Can I configure my NIS server to serve a different `auto.master` file to different clients? Or can I in some other way realize to automount directories only on specific clients, so that on all the other clients nothing gets overmounted?