# Ubuntu/OpenLDAP/Autofs : local user instead of LDAP user

Tags: ubuntu, openldap, autofs

I mount home directories for my LDAP users trhough autofs. It works like a charm except with one computer. On LDAP logs, I have :

```
ldap rpc.mountd[975]: authenticated mount request from 192.168.0.XX:845 for /export/home/adminlocal (/export/home)
ldap rpc.mountd[975]: can't stat exported dir /export/home/adminlocal: No such file or directory
```

Adminlocal is a local account and not an LDAP one.
Weird thing : These logs appears before login screen (actually, login screen doesn't display, stay black with loading cursor).

I tried switch +auto.master and +dir:/etc/autofs/auto.master.d in auto.master ([Failing to prevent autofs from mounting over local home directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/828862/failing-to-prevent-autofs-from-mounting-over-local-home-directory/833259#833259)). No effect
I also tried to add adminlocal    /- in my auto.home ([How to prevent autofs from mounting over specific directories?](https://serverfault.com/questions/245121/how-to-prevent-autofs-from-mounting-over-specific-directories)). I get :

```
ldap rpc.mountd[1000]: authenticated mount request from 192.168.0.XX:740 for /export/home/.Trash-1000 (/export/home)
ldap rpc.mountd[1000]: can't stat exported dir /export/home/.Trash-1000: No such file or directory
```

On other computers, no problem with mounting....